# max. distance of a number greater than a given number in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

i was going through an interview question ..and came up with logic that requires to find:

> Find an index `j` for an element `a[j]` larger than `a[i]` (with `j < i`), such that `(i-j)` is the largest. And I want to find this `j` for every index `i` in the array, in `O(n)` or `O(n log n)` time with `O(n)` extra space.`

What I have done until now :

1) `O(n^2)` by using simple `for loop`s

2) Build balanced B.S.T. as we scan the elements from left to right and for `i`'th element find index of element greater than it. But I realized that it can easily be `O(n)` for single element, therefore `O(n^2)` for entire array.

I want to know if it is possible to do it in `O(n)` or `O(n log n)`. If yes, please give some hints.

EDIT : i think i am unable to explain my question . let me explain it clearly:
i want `arr[j]` on left of `arr[i]` such that `(i-j)` is the largest possible ,and `arr[j]>arr[i]` and find this for all index i i.e.`for(i=0 to n-1).`

EDIT 2 :example - `{2,3,1,6,0}`
`for 2 , ans=-1`
`for 3 , ans=-1`
`for 1 , ans=2`  (i-j)==(2-0)
`for 6 , ans=-1`
`for 0 , ans=4`  (i-j)==(4-0)

Comment: Can you give an example of input and output data?

Comment: I don't quite get the question, is it to find the farthest element to the left, which is larger than current element, for each element in the array?

Comment: I'm not sure I got the sense properly, but isn't it about finding `min` and `max` in array and then compare? I.e: `[1. Find min]; [2. Find max]; [3. For given i-th element compare which is farther - min or max].` That's it. Nothing can be farther by definition of linear order.

Comment: arr[i] < arr[j] AND maximize arr[i]-arr[j] means you are basically looking for the closest element which is higher then arr[j]. Is it indeed the case? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo and @ShashankGupta: The element at index `j` to be found needs to be larger than `a[i]`, if you read the question thoroughly.

Comment: @justhalf so what? Then search only `max` in your array (I though only distance matter) - it's even easier. No element could be greater than `max` and greatest distance will be between element and `max` (yet again - due to linear order)

Comment: Please clarify - are you trying to maximize the distance between i and j, or the difference arr[i]-arr[j] ?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: The index `j` needs to be smaller than `i`. The `max` element might be on index `k` > `i`. Consider the case `[2, 4, 1, 5, 3]`. The answer for each element is `[-1, -1, 0, -1, 1]`, assuming you put `-1` on indices `i` where you can't find `j` such that `arr[j] > arr[i]` and `j < i`

Comment: @all `i-j should be maximum` not arr[i]-arr[j]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create an auxillary array of maximums, let it be `maxs`, which will basically contain the max value on the array up to the current index.

Formally: `maxs[i] = max { arr[0], arr[1], ..., arr[i] }`

Note that this is pre processing step that can be done in `O(n)`

Now for each element `i`, you are looking for the first element in maxs that is larger then `arr[i]`. This can be done using binary search, and is `O(logn)` per op.

Gives you total of `O(nlogn)` time and `O(n)` extra space.

Comment: there are two things that are not clear with your solution: 1. How exactly do you apply binary search on the max array in a O(logn) time? it may look like [10, 10, 18, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24] 2. Your algorithm is not complete - after looking for the first max element you need to store the value of i - j(along with the indexes) somewhere(another array) and at the  end find the maximum of of this array(or do this as you go along the max array)

Comment: @Bond Binary search is working perfectly for such an array, it is sorted, and you are guaranteed to find the closest equal/higher element in `O(logn)` time. The duplicate entries are not making the array 'unsorted', so condition for binary search still apply. The value retrieved from the binary search is the requested element for each `i`. You can also get the relevant index by finding the first entry with this value, but it is not needed as far as I understood, and anyway does not change time complexity.

Comment: @amit you are wrong as you are only finding max{arr[0],......arr[i-1]}  but we have to find max(i-j)

Comment: @anon Since it is an array of maximums, it is guaranteed that the element we find is the first one which is greater then arr[i] - which means it also maximized i-j, because no element with element smaller then j is higher then arr[i].

Comment: @amit i understood what you are trying to explain. i am not able to analyze the binary search . do you mean something like this ?
i assume that in maxs[i] = index of largest element, not largest element and target is arr[i]. bin_srch(start,end)
 {
   if(end<start) return -1
   if(arr[end]<target) return -1
   if(arr[start]>target) return start
   
   if(arr[mid]>target && mid-1>0 && arr[mid-1]>target)
    bin_srch(start,mid-1)
   else if(arr[mid]>target) 
    return mid
   else return bin_srch(mid+1,end)

 }

Comment: @anon I find it hard to follow your code here, binary search is a well known procedure, have a look at the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: @amit i am sorry couldn't format it properly ..
please open this link http://ideone.com/1pmXp3

Comment: @amit please see my code and tell if it is right or not .
if it is wrong then i am not able  to understand your solution.

Comment: @int The idea looks fine, some issues like not defining `mid`, not accepting `target` as an argument etc, but generally it seems correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in O(n) time using a stack data structure for array indexes for which you have yet to find a solution. It can be implemented as an array of at most n elements.

Iterate over the input array from left to right, starting with the last element:

- Pop all indexes from the stack for which the array element is less than the current element. Mark the index of the current element as the solution for each index you pop.
- Push the index of the current element on the stack.

Invariant: the array items corresponding to the indexes in the stack are always in ascending order, with the least item on top.

When you reach the beginning of the input, mark any items that still remain on the stack with -1; for them there is no answer.

Each array index is pushed into the stack exactly once and popped at most once, so this algorithm runs in O(n) time.

An example in Python:

```
def solution(arr):
    stack = []
    out = [-1]*len(arr)
    for i in xrange(len(arr)-1, -1, -1):
        while len(stack) > 0 and arr[stack[-1]] < arr[i]:
            out[stack.pop()] = i
        stack.append(i);
    return out
```

Note that the correct answer for input `[2, 4, 1, 5, 3]` is `[-1, -1, 1, -1, 3]`: for a fixed i, the difference j-i is greatest when j is greatest, so you are looking for the *leftmost* index j, which *minimizes* the distance. (When j < i, the difference j-i is negative.)

Comment: Oh ya, true. Just realized that "largest j-i" is not the greatest distance, but the minimum distance. This needs to be clarified with OP, whether he actually wants largest distance or truly largest j-i

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake in editing the post. The real question was the "largest i-j". Really sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution I can think of is allocating a second array and scanning the array left-to-right. As you traverse the array and scan each element, append the index of the element to your second array if arr[index] is greater than the right-most element of your second array. This is O(1) time per append, maximum of n appends, so O(n).

Finally, once your array is complete, take a second pass through your array. For each element, scan your second array using binary search (this is possible since it is implicitly sorted) and find the leftmost (earliest inserted) index j in your array such that arr[j] > arr[i].

To do this, you have to do a modification of binary search. If you find an index j such that arr[j] > arr[i], you still have to check to see if there are any indices k to the left such that arr[k] > arr[i]. You must do this until you find the left-most index.

I *think* this is O(log n) per binary search and you have to do the search for n elements. So the total time complexity would be close to O(n log n), but I am not sure of this. Any comments/suggestions to this answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are comparing the value of `arr[index]` with the right most element in second array, which contains an index. So you are comparing an element with an index? Or did you mean to compare with the element pointed by the right most element in the second array?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution in C++
We maintain an increasing array. Compare the current element with the element at the back of the array.
If it is larger or equals to the larget element so far, then append this element to the array, return -1, there's no smaller element on its left.

If not, we use a binary search, find the index and return the difference.
(We still need to append vec.back() to the array, because we cannot change the index)

```
int findIdx(vector<int>& vec, int target){
    auto it = upper_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), target);
    int idx = int(it-vec.begin());
    return idx;
}

vector<int> farestBig(vector<int>& arr){
    vector<int> ans{-1};
    vector<int> vec{arr[0]};
    int n = (int)arr.size();
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
        if(arr[i] >= vec.back()){
            ans.push_back(-1);
            vec.push_back(arr[i]);
        }
        else{
            int idx = findIdx(vec, arr[i]);
            ans.push_back(i-idx);
            vec.push_back(vec.back());
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```